# Injecting service to component dependent of context

Tags: angular, angular-providers

I have structure like this

```
@Injectable()
export class A extends B ...

@Injectable()
export class C extends B ...

@Component({})
 constructor(
      @Inject(SERVICE) public data // How to inject component
  ) {
  }
```

I have to dynamically inject service A or C to component

Comment: what is the condition you want to check before injecting it ?

Comment: i don't want checking any condition

Comment: If i understand correctly, you want to inject the service based on some context. What is the context. If there is no context why not inject both service ?

Comment: you can simply define a service in constructor. you don't have to inject it by *INJECT* method

Comment: Can you be more specific with your question?

Comment: `I have to dynamically inject service A or C to component` and `i don't want checking any condition`. There has to be some type of criteria for what type you want injected right? You want a random type in your service at run time.... do you? That would lead to unexpected or chaotic results.

Comment: Service A and C are data providers. Service which i have to inject depend from router params

Comment: Your question is still not making any sense. Do you mean you want to inject an array of all your types that extend `B`? Or do you want to inject a specific implementation that extends `B`?

Comment: I want to  inject a specific implementation that extends B

Answer (score 0):

> I want to inject a specific implementation that extends `B`

In that case you need only specify the type. This can be inferred from the argument type or it can defined explicitly as the argument in [`@Inject`](https://angular.io/api/core/Inject)

```
constructor(private myService: C) { }
```

or

```
constructor(@Inject(C) private myService: B) { }
```

Answer (score -2):

try this angular **reflectiveInjector** https://angular.io/api/core/ReflectiveInjector

This will help to get a service dynamically.

**Note:** Deprecated: from **v5** - slow and brings in a lot of code, Use `Injector.create` instead.

> An Injector is a replacement for a new operator, which can automatically resolve the constructor dependencies.
>
> In typical use, application code asks for the dependencies in the
>   constructor and they are resolved by the Injector.

Try the new `Injector`:

```
import { Injector } from '@angular/core';

const injector = Injector.create([
  {
    provide: ASerive,
    useClass: ASerive,
    deps: [specify if any dependency]
  }
]);
const gotMySerive = injector.get(ASerive);
```

Change the create data according to you needs

Comment: That is marked as deprecated. What is the non-deprecated way to achieve this?

Comment: Deprecated: from v5 - slow and brings in a lot of code, Use Injector.create instead, edited the answer